# Handling unique INSERTs(strings) in SQL that are used in the system like types

Tags: sql, database, duplicates

I have a table which are the activities that the technicians do to the machines. Columns are:

```
 1. ID
 2. NAME_ACT
```

What if the user writes and saves the activity *Change of oil RT54*, and the next month he forgot that the activity is already in the system and start doing it again, but this time he writes *Change of oil RT54* 2 spaces after change.

How should i handle this?

This is the "event form" that uses these activities

[image]

The user clicks the checkedlistbox and chooses the activity he did in the date he picked.

This is the form that allows the user add new activities

[image]

The user just writes the name of the activity and saves.

The id of the activity is a field in the table that increments as the user add new activities.

What can I do?

Comment: No seriously, what do you want to do? Prevent this from happening or correct the duplicated data?

Comment: You need to come up with clear rules for what you consider duplicates. For example, "records are duplicates if the values match after trimming whitespace from left and right of the string and taking the uppercase value.". Your rules may be different. Then enforce those rules in your application or with a database constraint.

Comment: Generally this is why data like this is defined once in the system so that the list of activities would not be free form text. From there the predefined list would be usable regardless of who enters the data. There is no 100% reliable way to solve this with free form text as an activity field.

Comment: the problem is that the activities are so vast and unpredictable that the user needs to insert it, so the system can do its thing with the stadistics and graph so it cant be predefined.